# Fuseki Sparql service not able to refer to external rdf resources

Tags: sparql, fuseki

I am not able to refer my sparql query to external rdf resources. I do not get any results. I am using Apache Fuseki. Could there be anything wrong in my settings? Thx.

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>

SELECT ?title
FROM <http://dig.csail.mit.edu/2008/webdav/timbl/foaf.rdf>
WHERE { ?s dc:title ?title .}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not from within Fuseki where `FROM`/`FROM NAMED` refer to graphs in the dataset being queried. This is what most people want. Long ago, it did pull from the web but that wasn't popular.

It works from the command line.